# JQGrid with scoll pagination and subgrid not working properly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jq grid with sub grid and its not working properly.On first page(page size = 20) it works fine and when i load second page by scrolling down the second page subgrid works but first page subgrid not working.Its send request when user exapnd the first page subgrid but its not showing up on the ui.No errors at the back.I tired with older and latest version of jqgrid but still not wokring following is my grid.

```
$("#gridList").jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',
        colNames:['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3', 'Col 4', 'Col 5', 'Col 6', 'Col 7', 'Col 8',  'Col 9', 'Col 9', 'Col 10', 'Col 11','Col 12'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'Col1', width:50, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col2', width:64, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col3', width:50, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col4', width:55, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col5', width:130, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col6', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col7', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col8', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col9', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col10', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col11', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col12', width:80, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
            {name:'Col13', index:'select', align:'center', width:80,}],
        width: 500,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        height: "470",
        scroll : true,
        rowNum : 20,
        rownumbers:true,
        loadtext: 'building list...'
        subGrid : true,
        subGridOptions: { 
            "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
            "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
            "reloadOnExpand" : false,
            "selectOnExpand" : true },
        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
            $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
            $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                datatype:'local',
                colNames: ['','Col 1','Col 2','Col 3','Col 4','Col 5'],
                colModel: [
                  {name: "&nbsp;", width:117, resizable: false},
                  {name: "Col1", width: 50, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
                  {name: "Col2", width: 55, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
                  {name: "Col3", width: 130, sortable: false, align:'center', resizable: false},
                  {name: "Col4", width: 165, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false},
                  {name: "Col5", width: 165, sortable: false, align:'right', resizable: false}
                ],
                height: "100%", 
                loadtext: 'building list...',
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                },
                idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_", 
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                }
            });

            fetchSubgridDetails(subgridId, rowid);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
        } 
    });
```

Comment: the usage of `scroll : true` or `scroll : 1` have a lot of restrictions. I don't recommend you to use it in combination with another advanced features like `subGrid : true`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg  I have to use `scroll:true` and with the sub grid the requirement is to have sub grid with pagination on scroll do you know how to solve this?  and I also seen your comment on the same problem.

Comment: I see no simple way to solve the problem. Virtual scrolling (`scroll: true` or `scroll: 1`) have too many restrictions. One should use it only in case of simple grid only. You have to remove `scroll : true` and use standard paging.